# RPN Calculator using header files for calc operations and stack; vector used for stack

Tags: c++, class, stack, header-files, rpn

I'm trying to create an rpn calculator, but have to use header files with class declaration and definitions for the calculator functions and the stack. I decided to use a vector for the stack, which I created in my stack.h file. Whenever I test the program, it keeps giving me my invalid token error, when entering a token that's not a given operator. I tried making it to where it was dealing with a vector for the values in rpn, I tried creating a function for a vector to return the vector in my stack header file, in order to instantiate and call it in my rpn header. None of this worked for me for some reason. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the result that I receive:

```
Please enter numbers and operators:
1 2 + =
Invalid token entered.
```

Here's my stack header file, called stack8.h

```
#ifndef STACK8
#define STACK8

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class stack8 {

    std::vector<double> rpn_stack;
    public:
        stack8();
        void push(double vals);
        double pop();
        void dump_op();
        int getsize();
        int i;
        string message;

};

stack8::stack8() {
    int values = 0;
}

void stack8::push(double vals) {
    rpn_stack.push_back(vals);  //pushing any double values found into the stack
    return; 
}
double stack8::pop() {
    double nums; //declaration for operands
    if (rpn_stack.size() <= 0) {  //checking for stack underflow
        std::cerr << "Stack underflow." << endl;
        //use_info.usage_info(message);
        exit(2);
    }
    else {
        nums = rpn_stack.back(); //if no stack underflow, values are user's input
        rpn_stack.pop_back();     //will pop the values at the top of the stack until the end based on user's input
        return nums;              //returning the result of values after popping
    }
}
int stack8::getsize() {
    std::cout<< rpn_stack.size() << " values remain on the stack." << endl; //number of vals in stack
    exit(3);
}

void stack8::dump_op() {
    for (i = 0; i < rpn_stack.size(); ++i) {  //iterating through stack to print values for dump operation
            cout << rpn_stack.at(i) << " ";
        }
}

#endif
```

Here is a snippet of what I have for the rpn.h header file.

```
#ifndef RPN8
#define RPN8

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

#include "stack8.h"
stack8 st;    //calling a stack class object to use for the calculator operations

class rpn8 {
    public:
        rpn8();
        double process();
        int getstacksize();
        double values;                 //declaration to use for our calculator operand values
        double tempo;                  //declaration to be used for temporary calc values for certain pop operations
        double r1, r2;                 //same as above, for use with certain pop operations
        string tokens;
        stringstream at;
    private:
        double result;

};

rpn8::rpn8() {
    result = 0;
}

double rpn8::process() {

    cout << "Please enter numbers and operators: " << endl;
    while (std::cin >> tokens) {
                //asking for user input for calculator operations
        at.str("");         //Looking for "" indicators
        at.clear();         //Removing the "" tokens
        at.str(tokens);     //Setting stringstream to user input entered
        at >> values;

        if (!at) {
            if (tokens.compare("+") == 0) {     //finding + in the input and popping two operands for addition

            st.push(st.pop() + st.pop());
            }
            else if (tokens.compare("-") == 0){ //finding - in the input and popping two operands for subtraction
            tempo = st.pop();       //using temporary value for subtracting operators
            st.push(st.pop() - tempo);
            }
            else if (tokens.compare("*") == 0) //finding * in the input and popping two operands for multiplication
            {
                st.push(st.pop() * st.pop());
            } 
            else if (tokens.compare("/")== 0) //finding / in the input and popping two operands for division
            {
                tempo = st.pop();

                if (tempo == 0) {  //if temp value = 0, division is undefined.  

                std::cerr<< "This results in division by 0, which is undefined.";
                exit(2);
                }
                st.push(st.pop() / tempo); //otherwise, carry out division from pop
            }
            else if (tokens.compare("'") == 0)
            {
                st.push(1.0 / st.pop());
            }
            else if (tokens.compare("~")== 0) //finding ~ to reverse sign of operand
            {
                st.push(-st.pop()); 
            }
            else if (tokens.compare("**") == 0) //finding ** for power function
            {
                tempo = st.pop();
                st.push(pow(st.pop(), tempo));
            }
            else if (tokens.compare("=") == 0) //time to print the final answer with the equal sign
            {
               std::cout<< "Result = "<< st.pop() << endl;  //printing results
               std::cout<< st.getsize() << " values remain on the stack." << endl; //# of vals in stack
            exit(3);
            }
            else if (tokens.compare("dump") == 0) {      //if dump is an operator entered
              st.dump_op();
              cout << endl;
              exit(4);
            }
            else {  //pushing values
                st.push(values);
            }
        }
        else {   //statement for if any invalid tokens are entered
            std::cerr << "Invalid token entered." << endl;  //error message printed before usage info and termination of program
            //help.usage_info(helps);
            exit(7);
        }       
    }
}
```

Here is my cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//adding a call for the rpn8.h header file
#include "rpn8.h"

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

    string help_info = "--help";  //string declaration for --help command-line arg
    string begin_prog = "-rpn";    //string declaration for -rpn command-line arg
    string usage_inf;              //string declaration to be used for argument when calling usage info function
    rpn8 calc;                      //instantiation of the rpn8 class



    if (argc == 1) {
        cerr << "Not enough arguments.";
        //help message...
    }
    else if (argc == 2 && (argv[1] == help_info)) { //if command-line arg is --help
        //usage_message(usage_inf);  //printing usage info
    }
    else if (argc == 2 && (argv[1] == begin_prog)) {  //if command-line arg is -rpn, starting calculator operations

        calc.process(); //calling the process function from rpn8 using call
    }
    else {
        cerr << "Too many command-line arguments or invalid arguments." << endl; //
        //usage_message(help_usage);
        exit(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Declaring `int values = 0;` inside the constructor doesn't accomplish anything useful. You don't appear to be processing `at` or iterating over `tokens` correctly.

Comment: Ahh ok, so I need to rethink how I'm processing the input. I used this method in a past program for an rpn calc and it worked, so I thought that it would work here. Also, probably because I'm using classes whereas the past one did not use classes. I will try again. Anything that you would recommend for how to properly deal with processing the string that is the user input?

Answer (score 0):

Your else-branch in `rpn8::process` is probably wrong. `if (!at)` will go to else-branch whenever you enter a number (when `st >> values` succeeds). But then you don't process this number, but rather handle it as an invalid token.

**Some other notes:**

- `std::cout<< st.getsize() << " values remain on the stack." << endl;` is somewhat strange, because `stack8::getsize` doesn't return anything but rather prints out the value and exits the whole program.
- `at.str("");` does not look for any indicators, but just replaces the content of the stringstream with an empty string.